# Resoled - JSONArray doesnt work in var but work in println- JSON Java AP -

Tags: java, json, discord

Hi I have a huge problem, voila, I have a JSON object that contains a JSONArray, when I test with `admin.has ("users")` it passes, it tells it, so I lem in a variable, except that it makes an error! So I debug in `System.out.println (admin.getJSONArray ("users"));`

My code:

```
    protected boolean isAdminUser(IUser user, IGuild guild) throws IOException {

    boolean allow=false;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));

    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(br.readLine());

    br.close();

    if(obj.has("admin")) {
        JSONObject admin = obj.getJSONObject("admin");
        if (admin.has("role")) {
            JSONArray role = obj.getJSONArray("role");
            List<Long> roleID=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Object roleOBJ: role.toList())
                roleID.add(Long.parseLong(roleOBJ.toString()));

            for(IRole roleU: user.getRolesForGuild(guild))
                if(roleID.contains(roleU.getLongID())) allow=true;
        }


        if(admin.has("users")) {

            System.out.println(admin.getJSONArray("users"));

            JSONArray users = obj.getJSONArray("users");
            List<Long> usersID=new ArrayList<>();
            for(Object userOBJ: users.toList())
                usersID.add(Long.parseLong(userOBJ.toString()));

            if(usersID.contains(user.getLongID())) allow=true;
        }
    }

    return allow;

}
```

And in my console:

```
 [292960007199129600,188932465996333057,494573579548098601]
22:27:17.576: [ERROR][Event Dispatcher Handler][sx.blah.discord.Discord4J] - Unhandled exception caught dispatching event MessageReceivedEvent
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["users"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:472)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:619)
    at fr.ph1823.orientbot.EventUtils.isAdminUser(EventUtils.java:155)
    at fr.ph1823.orientbot.events.CustomCommandListener.commandSend(CustomCommandListener.java:116)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher$MethodEventHandler.handle(EventDispatcher.java:680)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher.lambda$null$17(EventDispatcher.java:610)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thank for you repy ! (sorry for my english)

Comment: JSONArray users = obj.getJSONArray("users");
change to 
JSONArray users = admin.getJSONArray("users");

Comment: Yes that's right, I'm really stupid and I have many times to check the names of variables and I have never made the connection .. Sorry to have bothered you for nothing!